# Can python callbacks be registered on viewport user actions?

Tags: python, 3d-view, add-on

Is it possible to have python callbacks invoked when a user does something like select an object, bone, vertex, etc...?

For example, imagine a FK/IK setup where clicking on certain bones trigger the FK/IK switch and other necessary modifications. This isn't precisely what I'm trying to do but it should get the point across.

Comment: Try a search on `msgbus`

Comment: Interesting. Looks like it lets you know about changes to datablocks. Not sure object selection qualifies. I tried some experiments to see if I could register interest in bpy.context.selected_objects but couldn't get my callback to be invoked. Maybe I need an example.

Comment: Not sure `msgbus` works with context. The other one to look at is a depsgraph update [handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html) which runs a lot.  or just remembered this one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160909/handle-vertex-property-changes-with-msgbus-subscribe-rna